# Looping through a drop down, how to select value?

Tags: php, mysql

When displaying a form on a page for a user to edit information, and the form consists of a drop down box, how do you loop through the selections in the dropdown box to select their predefined mySQL entry?

For example

Users country: Australia

How would I go about searching through a list of countries ie: http://snipplr.com/view/4792/country-drop-down-list-for-web-forms/ to make:

```
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
```

become

```
<option value="AU" selected="selected">Australia</option>
```

Comment: Do not create every and each option for all countries separately. Try better approach create DB table for countries. Loop through them to echo drop down. Fetch the previously selected value and compare with list and echo 'selected'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<?php
$countries = array('AU' => 'Australia', 'AF' => 'Afghanistan', ...);
$selected = 'AU';
foreach ($countries as $code => $label) {
    echo '<option value="' . $code . '"';
    if ($selected == $code) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
?>
```

Not the prettiest but you get the idea.  As Shakti suggests, it's also easier to maintain if the values are in the DB and not in a massive array in the middle of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Could be something like this:

```
<?php
//your query here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY code ASC";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);

while($country = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
    if ($country["code"] == "AU"){
        echo "<option value=\"{$country['code']}\" selected=\"selected\">{$country['name']}</option>";
}
    else {
        echo "<option value=\"{$country['code']}\">{$country['name']}</option>";
    }       
?>
```